# Prove $p \rightarrow \neg \neg p$ with Hilbert System

Tags: logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $\beta \rightarrow \neg \neg \beta$ is a theorem using standard axioms 1,2,3 and MP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/prove-that-beta-rightarrow-neg-neg-beta-is-a-theorem-using-standard-axiom)

I need to prove $p \rightarrow \neg \neg p$

My question is very similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/prove-that-beta-rightarrow-neg-neg-beta-is-a-theorem-using-standard-axiom), but with some differences. Axiom 3 that I'm using is different (though I've heard is equivalent) and the ONLY things I am allowed to use are the following three axioms, MP, and the Deduction Theorem:

A1: $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$

A2: $(A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$

A3: $(\neg A \rightarrow \neg B) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$

If another theorem/axiom is needed to solve this, it must be proven in-line of the main question. You cannot prove the extra theorem on the side and then use it in the proof.

Comment: Also [Proving (α → ¬¬α) in Hilbert System](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90083/proving-in-hilbert-system)

Comment: I did reference the first link before, but it uses $\neg \neg p \rightarrow p$ as an already proven theorem. I would have to prove it within my proof so I wouldn't be able to use deduction theorem for it

Comment: The answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/21241/630 answers this too. As they point out, all that is needed are axiom schemes 1 and 2 and MP